# cannot resolve symoble scalatest in for Intellij IDE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I have switched from Eclipse to Intellij very recently. I have a maven project (dropwizard) and I am trying to create testcases for it and would like to use scala to implement unit/integration tests. using Command+Shift+T i have created a default Scala test class:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack


class ExampleSuite extends FunSuite {
//....
}
```

but IDE is complaining that 
cannot resolve symbole scalatest. 
I am using Intellij Scala plugin version 1.3.3 and my jvm version 1.7. 
initially IDE warns me about not having set up a SDK from Scala and configured it with the latest version (2.11.1)

Comment: The jar containing those definitions is not known to the IDE. Are you still using Maven? Did you tell the IDE where to find your Maven repository?

Comment: @RyanJ are you suggesting i should include the scala libs in my maven project?  my impression is that scalatest comes with the IDE and intellij should know how to deal with it the same way it deals with JUnit files, am i wrong?

Comment: It's my impression that the specific feature you're trying to use is not supplied with the Scala plugin framework that is bundled with IDEA. It appears to be supplied via a separate Maven repository, that needs to be included in your project. I'm not able to test if that's the case with my installation at the moment, but that looks like what your issue might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a dependency definition in your Maven POM?

The instructions for configuring ScalaTest for different environments are [here](http://www.scalatest.org/download).